# Start Second Activity instead of First android

Tags: java, android

For example, First time i want to start first activity eq: login screen. I validate the screen, if it is success i want to show dashboard screen.
For the second time, I directly want to show dashboard screen instead of login. Is it possible to directly start

Comment: You can implement something called OAuth for mobile application

Comment: you can achieve this through Shared Preferences by maintaining the boolean value.Set the value when first time you logged in and again start the app, you can fetch that boolean value.Depending on this you can make transitions.

Comment: @AkashG where i can used preference, checking in first activity's onCreate()

Comment: yes you can check it there only.if the condition gets satisfied than move to next activity else remain on the same activity.

Comment: That means when i was in dashbord screen. if user click back button it goes to login screen, i dont to go it

Comment: than you can implement onBackPressed in dashbord screen and setFalg in intent as Intent intent = new Intent(DashBoardActivity.this, FirstActivity.class);intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);startActivity(intent);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In First Activity If login is successful then store flag value is true in sharedpreferences and next time check if sharedpreferences value is true in splashscreenactivity then directly open dashboard activity, Use below code to save shared preferences on login successful.

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putString("Flag Value","True");
editor.commit();
```

For get SharedPreferences data into SplashScreen Activity:-

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String FlagValue = preferences.getString("Flag Value","");

if(FlagValue.equals("True")){
    Intent intent=new Intent(this, DashBoard_Activity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Is there is any other way to use shared preference without creating splash screen?

Comment: @kumaand Without using dummy activity how can you check user is loggedin or not?

Answer (score 2):

use SharedPreferences in your project.

put your strings in preferences

```
Editor edit = preferences.edit();
edit.putString("pref_empId", "1");
edit.putString("pref_userName", "kiran");
edit.putString("pref_userType", "ADMIN");
edit.commit();
```

next time check

```
pref_userName = preferences.getString("pref_userName", "n/a");
pref_empId    =  preferences.getString("pref_empId","n/a");
pref_userType =  preferences.getString("pref_userType","n/a");

if(!pref_userName.equals("") || !pref_userName.equals("n/a"))
{
   // go to login activity
}
else
{
  // dash board activity
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Preferances for checking weather it is a valid user are not. if it is then you can allow to enter into the second Activity.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to make a dummy activity. All it does is if person  is logged in or not. If he isn't launch the login activity, else launch the dashboard activity.

I usually put a splash screen here for the app and show the app's name or something with a nice image.

Answer (score 0):

Follow The Sequence like
1. login Screen
2. Before Opening the Validate Screen finish the Login Screen
3. After Successful validation open  dashword screen

```
      Intent in = new Intent(Login.this,Validation.class);
      startActivity(in);
      this.finish();

      Intent in = new Intent(Validation.this,Dashword.class);
      startActivity(in);
      this.finish();
```